# css responsive grid for columns with different width items

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I have a grid that has two columns, that needs to change to a two-row container on smaller screens.
I've been doing that with `repeat(auto-fit, 1fr)`.

But now I wanted to do the same responsive grid for a grid with first column width of 30% and the second with 70% width.

how can I make it responsive for items with different width?

I tried this

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, auto);
```

Or

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
```

But no luck. why is this not working?

**I wanted to do this with the grid, without media queries**

Comment: You can't...what's wrong with media queries? They are an essential part of responsive design.

Comment: You CSS has no way of setting the proportions you want without stating them in your grid-template-column property

Comment: @Paulie_D, I know they are essential. I am looking for a way to do that with grid only, since I want it to automatically adjust itself, without hardcoding device width, since width of the column might change for dynamic content

Comment: Well as I said you can't. If you want a 30/70 split you have to define it somewhere...